# Android Alert Dialog Looping

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

Hy,

im using AlertDialog to show a 'step by step' looping. In "log.d" the order is ok, it prints 1,2,and 3, but in Dialog, it prints 3,2 and 1.

How can i solve this?

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {    
    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(mainActivity);
    alert.setTitle("Test");
    alert.setMessage("n: " + (i + 1)); 

    Log.d("svn", "n: "+(i+1)); //it works!

    alert.setPositiveButton("ok!",
      new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
         int whichButton) {        
        // do nothing
       }});

    alert.show();    
   }
```

Comment: Well, its because your dialog that has "n: 1" gets displayed first and the other dialogs are displayed on top of it.

Comment: uhm, thats right. But... how can i "pause" the stack until the user touch the OK button? –  Bruno Savoini 11 hours ago

Comment: In your code you have a comment //do nothing. Thats where you need to display another dialog. when user touches ok button the onClick is invoked, but does nothing..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems that you create 3 dialogs, one on top of another.
Dialogs are created in correct order "1" -> "2" -> "3" and each is stacked on top of the previous ones.
That is why you see dialog "3" first, when you close it you will see "2" beneath and so on.